# Making areas of background image clickable

Tags: html, background

So ive got this part of the background image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCmsF.png)

I want the door and window area to be clickable, like a button that will hide this current background image and reveal another. How can I do that? I know there are some options with img tags, but had no luck with background images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding boxes with `<div id="box1"></div>`

Add a height,width,position,(margin,padding) and opacity: 0;

This way you have a transparant box(Make them black to get the right placement, change them afterwards!)

Comment: So just as expected, the solution is pretty boring to do.
Since im still a newbie, is there any easy way to determine the height and position I should have or its a matter of trying until i get this right?

Comment: You should just try until its alright, if you want the clickable area to be the perfect shape of the door, there should be enough ways to do that by css. (Don't know them myself, but I know they are there)

Comment: It's going to be tedious, but as long as it works... Thanks!

Comment: Just realised one thing. I can make it work in my resolution, but on screens with different sizes the div might be too large or too small.

Comment: Add a percentage instead of pixels, it's a bit tricky and will take more time, but this way it will be dynamic.